# Angular Js get input element by ng-repeat on document ready

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to bind jquery-ui datepicker to input fields which are located in ng-repeat generated table using **$(document).ready()**.
 I found that no elements get selected from table on execution of document ready function.

Please refer below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dateinputs = $('.dateinput');//no element get selected
 //loop to bind datepicker to each jquery selected control
});
```

Comment: could you please share a jsfiddle link with your problem statement and share relevant html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh i have a work around, see if it solves your problem.

in HTML code I did:

```
<input  type='text' class='dateinput {{initDatePicker()}}' />
```

Then in the JS code:

```
$scope.initDatePicker = function (){
    jQuery('.dateinput ').datepicker({'changeMonth':true,'changeYear':true,'dateFormat':'dd/mm/yy'});
}
```

It is a bit dirty but it is working.  Best i can think of for now.